# Ubuntu 11.10 Dell M4600 ATI Radeon HD6700M Dual Monitors

Tags: 11.10, ati, dell, radeon

I am having problems with my m4600 supporting dual monitors.

I have a ATI Radeon HD 6700M (from lspci) and have installed the ATI proprietary drivers for that model and followed the instructions found here.

The resolution is fine, however, when I first boot, the resolution is mirrored across both of my 1280x1024 monitors (computer is docked). When I attempt to change it to span my desktop using (as root) amdcccle, it logs me off and I have to log in again. I log in and the mirrored setup is the default again. If I try to uncheck the mirrored monitors using the Ubuntu display manager (default display application), it will log me off as well.

I had this working before the .xsession-errors file filled up my HDD and I was forced to shutdown. I reinstalled the ATI drivers like I said above, but cannot get this to work. I love Ubuntu, just not on Dells :).

Anyone have any solutions or advice on some next steps?

Answer (score 1):

If you have dual graphics cards, consider using vgaswitcheroo and only using the integrated graphics card. I had nothing but trouble trying to make my fancy video work with my HP laptop.

```
1GB Radeon(TM) HD 6770M GDDR5 Graphics [HDMI, VGA]
```

I tried both the "suggested" proprietary drivers as well as fglrx. You are in for a world of pain trying to make this card work if you also have integrated video.

Good luck.