# Dual monitors on ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, multiple-monitors

I checked solution from [other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72532/ubuntu-11-10-dell-m4600-ati-radeon-hd6700m-dual-monitors) but after entering NVidia settings>X Server Display Configuration I get:

> Unable to load X Server Display Configuration page:
>
> Failed to query NoScanout for screen 0.

I have 2 Dell monitors, settings see only 1 unknown monitor.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the same issue with my nvidia driver on my gateway. This happened when I updated the nvidia driver to the new driver as suggested by ubuntu. Try to "roll back" the driver to the original driver on first load. see if that helps.  This works on Ubuntu 11.10 I am not sure about server version.